# Integral of the boundary of a ball (spherical coordinates)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

There is a part in my notes where (when finding the distributional Laplacian of $1/|\textbf{x}|$) we note that $$\int_{B_\epsilon (0)} \phi \, \mathrm{d}x \approx 4\pi\epsilon^2 \phi(0)$$ and $$\int_{B_\epsilon (0)} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}\, \mathrm{d}x =\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2).$$ Supposedly this is true for small $\epsilon$ because $B_\epsilon (0)$ is the surface of the sphere.

I don't understand either of these integrals. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, observe
\begin{align}
\phi(x) = \phi(0) + \nabla\phi(0)\cdot x+\mathcal{O}(|x|^2)
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)}\phi(x)\ dx \approx& \int_{B_\varepsilon(0)} \phi(0)\ dx +\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)}\nabla\phi(0)\cdot x\ dx +\text{ remainder}\\
\approx&\ \phi(0)\operatorname{Area}(B_\varepsilon(0)) = 4\pi\varepsilon^2 \phi(0)
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)} \nabla\phi(0)\cdot x\ dx\right| \leq C\int_{B_\varepsilon(0)} |x|\ dx \leq C\varepsilon^3
\end{align}
and likewise for the remainder term.

The second equation follows the exact same line of argument.

Comment: I understand most of that except the first line where $\phi(x)=\phi(0)+\nabla\phi(0)⋅x+\mathcal{O}(|x|^2)$. I'm not sure if it is clear but $\phi \not= 1/|\textbf{x}|$. Rather this is one of the steps involved in finding the distributional Laplacian in spherical corrdinates for $f(x)=1/|\textbf{x}|$.

Comment: Never mind I just realized you use taylor expansion.